# current table name in a transaction postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

I haven't used postgreSQL much. I want to retrieve current table name in a TRANSACTION. Is there any way I can retrieve current locked table name in a transaction?

Comment: There is no such thing as the "current table" in a transaction. A single transaction can use hundreds of tables (delete from one, insert into another, select from a third, update another). The question doesn't make sense

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I might not be an accurate with my question as I am not aware if above things are possible in a postgresSQL. What I meant was do have an access of locked tables at any point?

Comment: A transaction does not necessarily lock a _table_. In fact this will only happen if you explicitely execute a `LOCK TABLE foo` from within your code. "Regular" DML statements only lock the _rows_ they work on, not the (whole) table. And if table locks are used locks - a transaction can again lock more than one table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: so I believe it's also not possible to get the name of table on which ROLLBACK was executed or is it?

Comment: Again: a rollback doesn't "execute on a table". It rolls back a _transaction_. If the transaction changed 100 tables, the rollback will affect 100 tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name A transaction acquires a lock on each table it accesses, actually. It's a weak lock, but it prevents the table from being dropped, prevents `vacuum full`, etc. Of course I totally agree with your explanation of the misunderstanding and this is just a minor detail.

Comment: @CraigRinger: yes I know. I thought adding that to my comment would confuse more than it would help.

Answer (score 0):

A transaction - or a statement within a transaction - can affect many tables.

What's the "current table" in the query:

```
select x.a, y.b
from x inner join y on (x.id = y.x_id);
```

?

Or in the transaction:

```
begin;

select * from x;

insert into y select a, b from x;    

update z set a = 42 where b = 7;
```

?

Your question doesn't make sense.

The only time there's any concept of a "current table" or anything resembling that is when you're inserting into, updating or deleting from a table, in which case the target table is clearly more significant. Even then though, table inheritance, views with `on update do instead` triggers, etc mean it might not be simple.

Whatever you're trying to do, you need to find another way to do it. I suspect there's a deeper misunderstanding at work here and you need to post a new question with the "why" behind this "how", i.e. why you want to be able to do this, what the underlying problem you're trying to solve is.